# Problem storing data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storing-data

I can't getting my stored data.... This is the code:

```
 if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        //RECUPERO DATA 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *pathToDocuments=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        pathToDocuments=[pathToDocuments stringByAppendingString:@"getSubscriptionsListShowOnlyWithUnreadFeeds.txt"];
        NSLog(pathToDocuments);
        dataReply=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToDocuments];
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"string recuperata %@",string);
    }
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]==NO) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *pathToDocuments=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        pathToDocuments=[pathToDocuments stringByAppendingString:@"getSubscriptionsListShowOnlyWithUnreadFeeds.txt"];
        NSLog(pathToDocuments);
        [dataReply writeToFile:pathToDocuments atomically:YES];}
```

Is there something wrong?

**EDIT**
No bugs no crashes but the `NSLog(@"string recuperata %@",string);` prints an empty string! (data are stored in the device because I had running at least one time my app when string!= empty
Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors/crashes/bugs?

Comment: No bugs, no crashes... but the NSLog(@"string recuperata %@",string);

Comment: No bugs no crashes but the NSLog(@"string recuperata %@",string); prints an empty string! (data are stored in the device because I had running at least one time my app when string!= empty

Comment: What is the output of `NSLog(pathToDocuments)`? Are you sure the file exists?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a else missing on the second if. I'm not sure if that is what you wanted or if it is a typo on your part. check if that is the problem.

```
 if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        //RECUPERO DATA 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *pathToDocuments=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        pathToDocuments=[pathToDocuments stringByAppendingString:@"getSubscriptionsListShowOnlyWithUnreadFeeds.txt"];
        NSLog(pathToDocuments);
        dataReply=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToDocuments];
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"string recuperata %@",string);
    } else if ([string isEqualToString:@""]==NO) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *pathToDocuments=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        pathToDocuments=[pathToDocuments stringByAppendingString:@"getSubscriptionsListShowOnlyWithUnreadFeeds.txt"];
        NSLog(pathToDocuments);
        [dataReply writeToFile:pathToDocuments atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I need to check 1st if the string is empty... if it is true I wan't to retrieve data to my device and alloc my string with it... so in the second if the string will be !=nil..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to `NSUTF8StringEncoding` if you are unsure about the encoding, usually it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ([string length]<=0) {
            //RECUPERO DATA 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *pathToDocuments=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        pathToDocuments=[pathToDocuments stringByAppendingString:@"getSubscriptionsListShowOnlyWithUnreadFeeds.txt"];
        NSLog(pathToDocuments);
        dataReply=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToDocuments];
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"string recuperata %@",string);
    }

    else {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *pathToDocuments=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        pathToDocuments=[pathToDocuments stringByAppendingString:@"getSubscriptionsListShowOnlyWithUnreadFeeds.txt"];
        NSLog(pathToDocuments);
        [dataReply writeToFile:pathToDocuments atomically:YES];

    }
```